# Why are there two results of the proof of the formula $\displaystyle 2\tan^{-1} x-\tan^{-1}\frac{x^{2} -1}{2x} =\frac{\pi }{2}$(x>0)?

Tags: inequality

Here is the process of my consideration:
Suppose $\displaystyle \tan\alpha =x,\ \tan\beta =\frac{x^{2} -1}{2x}$.
So the formular could be $\displaystyle 2\alpha -\beta =\frac{\pi }{2}$, and there are two options to prove whether the formula is established:
(1)$\displaystyle 2\alpha =\frac{\pi }{2} +\beta \ $
(2)$\displaystyle \frac{\pi }{2} -2\alpha =-\beta $

The proof process from (1)
$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
\tan2\alpha =\frac{2x}{1-x^{2}}\\
\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} +\beta \right) =-\tan\beta =\frac{x^{2} -1}{2x}
\end{array}$

$\displaystyle \therefore $The left and right sides of the equation are not equal, the original formula does not hold

The proof process from (2)
$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}\
\tan\left(\frac{\pi }{2} -2\alpha \right) =\frac{1}{\tan2\alpha } =\frac{1-x^{2}}{2x}\\
\tan( -\beta ) =-tan\beta =-\frac{x^{2} -1}{2x} =\frac{1-x^{2}}{2x}
\end{array}$

$\displaystyle \therefore $The left and right sides of the equation are equal, the original formula is established

The results above are confusing me, I guess I missed some details.
The formula is proven by the second option from the reference answer. But I can't understand why the first option doesn't work.

By the way, except "α" is the first quadrant angle, is there another else hint from the condition "x>0"?

I'm not an English speaker, so If there is any problem with the grammar to confuse you, please let me know. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you mean $\pi$?

Comment: yes @DavidG.Stork

Comment: $\tan((\pi/2)+\beta)\ne-\tan\beta$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\tan\left(\frac{\Pi }{2} +\beta \right) = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\Pi }{2} +\beta \right)}{\cos \left(\frac{\Pi }{2} +\beta \right)}= \frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\beta + \cos\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\beta}{\cos\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\beta - \sin\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\beta}= -\cot \beta=\frac{2x}{1-x^2}
$$
OR
$$\tan\beta = \frac{x^2-1}{2x}$$

Comment: using capital pi, that's bold. +1

Comment: Thank your answer.